# Ax = b solver on coordinate matrix Apache Spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I solve the Ax = b problem using Apache spark. My input is a coordinate matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import sparse
row = np.array([0, 3, 1, 0])
col = np.array([0, 3, 1, 2])
data = np.array([4, 5, 7, 9])
A = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(4, 4))
#take the first column of A
b = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, 1)), shape=(4, 1))

#Solve Ax = b
np.linalg.solve(A,b)
```

Now I want to solve for x in Ax=b using the python libraries of the Apache Spark framework so the solution should be [1,0,0,0] since b is the 1st column of A

Below is the Apache Spark linear regression. Now, how do I set up the problem such that the input is a coordinate matrix (A) and coordinate vector (b)?

```
   from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

# Load training data
training = spark.read.format("libsvm")\
    .load("data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt")

lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)

# Fit the model
lrModel = lr.fit(training)

# Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
print("Coefficients: %s" % str(lrModel.coefficients))
print("Intercept: %s" % str(lrModel.intercept))

# Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
print("numIterations: %d" % trainingSummary.totalIterations)
print("objectiveHistory: %s" % str(trainingSummary.objectiveHistory))
trainingSummary.residuals.show()
print("RMSE: %f" % trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError)
print("r2: %f" % trainingSummary.r2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve the Ax = b problem using Apache spark.

Directly (analytically) you cannot. Spark doesn't provide linear algebra library.

Indirectly - use [`pyspark.ml.regression`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html) to approximately solve OLS problem. You can refer to:

- [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression).
- [MLlib guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression)

for details regarding expected input and required steps.